# What does all the positioning properties of sprites in PIXI.js v4 do?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

What does all the position properties and functions on a pixi.js sprite / DisplayObject actually do? You can access `sprite.x`, `sprite.width`, `sprite.getBounds()`, `sprite.toLocal()`, `sprite.toGlobal()`, `sprite.getGlobalPosition()`, `sprite.getLocalBounds()`.

And how are they affected by scale, pivot, position and parent properties?

---

I was very confused with all the various ways to get positioning from PIXI.js sprites, and didn't find the documentation helpful, so I created an example, to help me get an overview (at the end of this post).

This example also creates a camera, that can be used to center the view on selectable sprites.

```js
// Size of the rectangles
const rectSize = 10;
// Rotation of the rotated rectangle
const rotation = 45;
// Zoom level of the camera, higher is closer
const zoomLevel = 2;
// Resolution of the app
const resolution = 1;









// Create the pixi app
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  backgroundColor: 0x000000,
  interactive: true,
  resolution: resolution
});
// HTML elements
const $body = $('body');
const $pixi = $('#pixi');
const $info = $('#info').find('tbody');

$pixi.append(app.view);

// Camera controls what we see
const camera = new PIXI.Container();
camera.scale.set(zoomLevel, zoomLevel);
app.stage.addChild(camera);

// Origin is the stage position - never move the stage
const origin = app.stage.position;

// Create some sprites
const rect = new PIXI.Graphics();
rect.beginFill(0xffffff);
rect.drawRect(0, 0, rectSize, rectSize);
const texture = app.renderer.generateTexture(rect);
const zeroedChild = PIXI.Sprite.from(texture);

const positionedChild = PIXI.Sprite.from(texture);
positionedChild.tint = 0xd83131
positionedChild.position.set(rectSize, rectSize);

const rotatedChild = PIXI.Sprite.from(texture);
rotatedChild.tint = 0x34d839;
rotatedChild.position.set(rectSize, rectSize);
rotatedChild.rotation = rotation * Math.PI / 180;

const scaledChild = PIXI.Sprite.from(texture);
scaledChild.tint = 0x4065d6;
scaledChild.position.set(rectSize, rectSize);
scaledChild.scale.set(2, 2);

const pivotedChild = PIXI.Sprite.from(texture);
pivotedChild.tint = 0xb637d6;
pivotedChild.position.set(rectSize, rectSize);
pivotedChild.pivot.set(pivotedChild.width / 2, pivotedChild.height / 2);

// Add all sprites to the camera
camera.addChild(zeroedChild, positionedChild, rotatedChild, scaledChild, pivotedChild);

updateInfo();

function updateInfo() {
  $info.html('');
  $info.append(info('Camera', camera, origin));
  $info.append(info('Zeroed Child', zeroedChild, origin));
  $info.append(info('Positioned Child', positionedChild, origin));
  $info.append(info(`Rotated Child (${rotation})`, rotatedChild, origin));
  $info.append(info('Scaled Child (2)', scaledChild, origin));
  $info.append(info('Pivoted Child (center)', pivotedChild, origin));
}

function info(name, sprite, origin) {
  const $row = $('<tr></tr>');
  if (sprite.parent) {
    if (!sprite.originalTint) {
      sprite.originalTint = sprite.tint;
    }

    $row.on('mouseenter', () => {
      const parent = sprite.parent;
      sprite.tint = 0xf4ff2b;
      parent.removeChild(sprite);
      parent.addChild(sprite);
    });
    $row.on('mouseleave', () => {
      sprite.tint = sprite.originalTint;
    });
    $row.on('click', () => {
      centerOn(sprite);
      sprite.parent.children.forEach((child) => {
        child.tint = child.originalTint;
      });
      sprite.tint = 0xf4ff2b;
    })
  }
  $row.append(`<td><b>${name}</b></td>`);
  $row.append(`<td>(${r(sprite.x)}, ${r(sprite.y)})</td>`);
  $row.append(`<td>(${r(sprite.toLocal(origin).x)}, ${r(sprite.toLocal(origin).y)})</td>`);
  $row.append(`<td>(${r(sprite.toGlobal(origin).x)}, ${r(sprite.toGlobal(origin).y)})</td/>`);
  $row.append(`<td>(${r(sprite.getGlobalPosition().x)}, ${r(sprite.getGlobalPosition().y)})</td>`);
  $row.append(`<td> (${r(sprite.scale.x)}, ${r(sprite.scale.y)})</td>`);
  $row.append(`<td>(${r(sprite.width)}, ${r(sprite.height)})</td>`);
  $row.append(`<td>(${r(sprite.getBounds().x)}, ${r(sprite.getBounds().y)}) | w: ${r(sprite.getBounds().width)}, h: ${r(sprite.getBounds().height)})</td>`);
  $row.append(`<td>(${r(sprite.getLocalBounds().x)}, ${r(sprite.getLocalBounds().y)}) | (${r(sprite.getLocalBounds().width)}, ${r(sprite.getLocalBounds().height)})</td></tr>`);


  return $row;
}


function r(n) {
  return Math.round(n * 100) / 100;
}

// Centers the camera on the given sprite
function centerOn(sprite) {
  if (sprite === camera) {
    camera.position.set(0, 0)
    updateInfo();
    return;
  }

 // Find the center of the renderer = canvas
  const centerRendererX = (app.renderer.width / resolution) / 2;
  const centerRendererY = (app.renderer.height / resolution) / 2;
  // Get the bounds of the sprite
  const bounds = sprite.getBounds();
  // Get the current position of the camera
  const cPos = camera.getGlobalPosition();
  // The bounds of the sprite is affected by the position of the camera (parent)
  // Subtract the camera position from the sprite position to put the sprite at it's original location
  // Then center it in the renderer/canvas, and find the middle of the sprite
  const x = centerRendererX - ((bounds.x - cPos.x) + bounds.width / 2);
  const y = centerRendererY - ((bounds.y - cPos.y) + bounds.height / 2);

  camera.position.set(x, y);
  updateInfo();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: courier;
}

b {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


#info {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

#info td {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#info tr:hover {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.7.0/pixi.min.js"></script>
<table id="info">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>(x, y)</th>
      <th>toLocal(stage)</th>
      <th>toGlobal(stage)</th>
      <th>getGlobalPosition()</th>
      <th>scale</th>
      <th>width/height</th>
      <th>getBounds()</th>
      <th>getLocalBounds()</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<div id="pixi">

</div>
```

([Source](https://jsfiddle.net/3ko5c1u8/16/))

Answer (score 3):

In PIXI.js v4:

- [`sprite.x`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html#x): This is an [alias for `sprite.position.x`](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/release/src/core/display/DisplayObject.js#L438-L441) (also says it [in the docs](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html#x) too).
- [`sprite.position.x`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html#position): The sprites *local* `x` position, pulled from the transform matrix (as `sprite.position` is an [alias for `sprite.transform.position`](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/release/src/core/display/DisplayObject.js#L492-L495)).
- [`sprite.width`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html#width): This is the width of the sprite in pixels. Updating this will update the scale of the sprite
- [`sprite.toGlobal( origin )`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.DisplayObject.html#toGlobal): The sprites *global* position based on a world origin of `origin`, in most cases `new PIXI.Point(0,0)` unless you have a different use case
- [`sprite.toLocal( position )`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.DisplayObject.html#toLocal): Takes a global `position` and makes it a position relative to the current sprite (applies [the inverse of the global transform](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/release/src/core/display/DisplayObject.js#L332) of this sprite).
- [`sprite.getBounds()`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.DisplayObject.html#getBounds): Returns a `PIXI.Rectangle` with global transforms (all parent transforms and local transforms) applied. `.x` is the *global* position x, same as `sprite.toGlobal( new PIXI.Point(0,0) ).x`
- [`sprite.getLocalBounds()`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.DisplayObject.html#getLocalBounds): Returns a `PIXI.Rectangle` with only local transforms applied (like `.rotation`). Slightly different from `.position.x` because it will be affected by `.rotation` and other transforms.
- [`sprite.getGlobalPosition()`](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.DisplayObject.html#getGlobalPosition): Returns the sprites *global* position [without any *local* transforms applied](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/d2a83b3fc457f6b0bd41dc5ca268fe1a05b4b50a/packages/mixin-get-global-position/src/index.js), just all of the parents transforms.

I found the documentation unhelpful as there are subtleties to getting a global position when there are local transformations like `.pivot` and `.rotations`. I found that the easiest way to get a global position when you only want *some* local transformations is to do something like.

```
let oldRot = sprite.rotation; 
sprite.rotation = 0;
let globalPosition = this.toGlobal(new PIXI.Point(0,0));
sprite.rotation = oldRot;
```

This will unapply the `.rotation` transformation when the matrix is rebuilt in `toGlobal` allowing you to get a position only affect by `.pivot`